# Building and finding a "page" in a tree-structure

Tags: java, scala

I want to provide an on disk tree structure which is capable of storing nodes in each page. Let's assume we have pages with four nodes in each page and four references to other pages.

```
So for instance:
Page 0: Level 0: 4 nodes (0, 1, 2, 3) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: page1, 1: page2, 2: page3, 3:page4),
Page 1: Level 1: 4 nodes (4, 5, 6, 7) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: page6, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null),
Page 2: Level 1: 4 nodes (8, 9, 10, 11) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null),
Page 3: Level 1: 4 nodes (12, 13, 14, 15) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null),
Page 4: Level 1: 4 nodes (16, 17, 18, 19) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null),
Page 5: Level 2: 4 nodes (20, 21, 22, 23) / 4 Pointers (offset 0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null),
```

I currently have no idea how to get the offset on each level to find the page. That is node-ID >> 2 should provide the page-ID, but how do I get the offset of the right pointer on each level in the tree?

For instance Page 6 in this very simple tree. Searching for page 6 should get offset 0 at first, that is page 2 starting from page 1 (the root-page). So I'm getting page 2, then it's once more offset 0 to follow.

Note that the pages should be ordered in Levelorder. I'm not sure if the approach is even possible.

Comment: Is this a Scala/Java question or an algorithms questions?

Comment: It's neither clear what you're asking nor what you're trying to accomplish. Please clarify.

Comment: It's a programming question, but I couldn't find the right "tags".